# Проблема при отправке post-запроса через Indy Client (IdHTTP)

Tags: c++builder, c++

Может вопрос очень примитивный и его решение есть в справке, но по-моему, тут ответят намного быстрее и понятнее, чем я найду.

Суть: отправляется post-запрос через Indy Client:

```
IdHTTP1->Post(url,list)
```

Проблема: когда запрос отправляется, программа, ожидая ответ, не отвечает (зависает). Как сделать так, что-бы программа оставалась активной во время ожидания ответа на запрос?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить комп. IdAntiFreeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай поток и в нем отправляй запрос и жди ответа...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
К сожалению, никогда не работал с потоками, а попробовав разобратся, мало что понял. Не могли бы вы описать приблизительно, либо скинуть ссылку, где потокиспользуется именно в таких/подобных целях?

Answer (score 0):

Компонент `IdAntiFreeze` решил проблему, спасибо [Timenzzo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3188/timenzzo) за совет. Со временем все-же переведу отправление запроса в другой поток, но пока этого способа вполне достаточно.